# Threads don't end properly

Tags: java, android

I have the problem that there seems to be some threads that aren't terminated right. When I pause one of this threads in debug mode I get this list:

```
Thread [<14> pool-2-thread-1] (Suspended)   
    <VM does not provide monitor information>   
    Object.wait(long, int) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread.parkFor(long) line: 1205 
    Unsafe.park(boolean, long) line: 325    
    LockSupport.park(Object) line: 159  
    AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() line: 2019   
    LinkedBlockingQueue.take() line: 413    
    ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() line: 1013 
    ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1073  
    ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 573   
    Thread.run() line: 841
```

before I paused it, it was "Running" instead of Suspended.
How can I find out which thread that is?

Comment: Well, this list is of course much more helpful than, let's say... the actual code.

Comment: i can't write my whole project here, i don't even know which thread this is... that's what i want to find out

Comment: 1. When creating a thread, you can name it by `setName()`. 2. You should investigate, under which conditions the thread's runnable implementation can return/terminate. If there is no such condition (or it's never met), then you've got the answer.

Comment: What's the problem then? You may not have  started that thread, the os could have, it seems like a thread in a pool used by an executor. What harm does it cause, why are you concerned about it?

Answer (score 0):

This Thread seems to be a "spare" thread kept in a thread pool, waiting for something to do. It is not executing your code.

This is completely normal.

Comment: the problem is, that when i back to my start activity and then do the same steps again, it starts a new thread for this. There fore if i do that more often, i get more and more threads. That's not very nice since i don't need anything from the old threads. How can i cancel these? I found out that there is a point where this thread is called using Thread.currentThread(). what can i do with this thread to terminate it?

Comment: How many Threads do you get? Check the section "Core and Maximum Pool Sizes" in this link whether it fits your problem: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html  It basically says, that up to a configured limit it does what you describe: start new Threads for a new task. However, once the core pool size is reached no new Threads should be created if there are idle ones.